# How to load js source map file correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I'm working on a single page application.Since I don't want to load all the js files for one time, so modules load js(**by jquery**) they need themselves.
But after I minify these js files with **sourcemapping**, there always get error : Failed to parse SourceMap.
i.e.
minifyed js file path : a/b/c.js
sourcemapping path : a/b/c.js.map
original js file path : a/b/c.uncompressed.js
Do the test like this : 
1. load js in main page html, **not by jquery**, it works fine.
2. load js by jquery, doesn't work, error message is : "Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost/c.js.map", the path "a/b" **lost**.

How can I load sourcemap file correctly? Thanks in advance.